# Creating new user MySQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi I'm developing app for a school project and I want need to create a user which will be saved in the database.

I've created a Profile class

```
public class Profile{

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public Profile(String _username, String _password){
        this.username = _username;
        this.password = _password;

    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String _password){
        this.password = _password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
```

Than I have created a DBConnect class which will contain all the methods one of them being CreateProfile which I want to user to Insert the values for new profile into the database "user" table.

```
public class DBConnect {

    private Connection dbConnection;

    public DBConnect(){

        try{
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Connection failed :" +ex);
        }
    }
    public void createProfile(Profile profile){
        Statement stm = null;
        try{
            stm = dbConnection.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO User (Username,Password) VALUES (\"" + profile.getUsername() + "\", \"" + profile.getPassword()+ "\"");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Finally in my JFrame I have two textFeilds username and password which I want to use in order to pass on the parameters for profile constructor. Once this is done I DBConnect object to start of the connection and than I'm calling the Create Profile method which is declared in the DBConnect.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Profile p = new Profile(jTextField1.getText(), jPasswordField1.getText());
    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
    dbc.createProfile(p);
```

Everything compiles but when I run the program and try to create a new Profile I get this Error.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

My MySQL tables is a simple table with two columns called 'Username' and 'Password'

Comment: Forget `Statement`, use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the right parenthesis inside the string:

```
stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO User (Username,Password) VALUES (\"" + profile.getUsername() + "\", \"" + profile.getPassword()+ "\")";
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to take a look! :-D

Comment: Yes that is very true ;)